# MySql Cluster for educational use

Tags: mysql-cluster, license

I am student and I am writing Master of Science paper about in-memory databases. I want to use MySql Cluster for benchmarks in my work.
Can I use MySql Cluster free of charge for educational purposes or do I need to pay for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [downloads](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/) page:

> It is available as both open source and commercial editions. The Community (OSS) Edition is available under the free software/opensource GNU General Public License (commonly known as the "GPL").

If GPL is ok for you, then you're fine. The Carrier Grade Edition is a commercial offering though. You'll need to contact Oracle to see if they have special pricing or licensing for educational purposes.